# Pyinstaller Tensorflow bundle fails

Tags: python, tensorflow, pyinstaller

Trying to run pyinstaller to compile a tensorflow application on windows. The file get's packaged perfectly, but i end up running into this error when running the resulting exe.

```
 File "site-packages\astor\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\me\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI138162\\astor\\VERSION'
```

I've ensured the `astor` package is included, and even tried to use the `--hiden imports` flag, but to no avail.

How can I properly include the astor package with pyinstaller?

Answer (score 3):

You can create "astor" folder in your project.
And paste VERSION file from "your env/Lib/site-packages/astor/VERSION".

-- [EDIT] --

On PyInstaller you should add the flag `--add-data 'astor:./astor'` to add the folder to the project, doesn't seem to need the source, just the `VERSION` file

Comment: This looks more like a comment then an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead); instead, provide answers according to [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: This can be resolved without the manual copy/paste, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59702200/pyinstaller-tensorflow-bundle-fails/61348746#61348746)

Answer (score 1):

I've run into the same issue and here is how I solved it ***without requiring any manual copy/paste***:

In my `.spec` file, I've added the following lines:

```
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import collect_data_files
a.datas += collect_data_files('astor', subdir=None, include_py_files=False)
```

**Explanation**

The error pointed to this statement in the site-packages' `astor/__init__.py`:

```
with open(os.path.join(ROOT, 'VERSION')) as version_file:
    __version__ = version_file.read().strip()
```

It seemed that the `VERSION` file present in the astor package was not being copied by pyinstaller, and therefore not found in the standalone folder produced. Using the `collect_data_files()` utils function and adding the results to the analysis' `datas` argument in my `.spec` file resolved the issue. Detailed info in the docs: https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/hooks.html?highlight=collect_data_files#useful-items-in-pyinstaller-utils-hooks

Comment: Alternatively, in the .spec file write directly
`datas=collect_data_files('astor')`

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this problem by going in to the astor/**init**.py file and changing the two lines you mentioned in your question to:

```
__version__ = '0.8.1'

parse_file = code_to_ast.parse_file
```

Pyinstaller worked perfectly after this.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. My astor package version was 0.8.1. I changed astor version to 0.7.1. It worked like a charm.